# Sending a SIGUSR2 Signal with Keystroke

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I'd like to send a SIGUSR2 signal to a foreground process in Ubuntu Server (v12.04). Is it possible to send this with a keystroke (maybe with stty, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can only send SIGINT, SIGQUIT, and SIGTSTP using keystrokes.  You can't send SIGUSR2.